# Swift Closure Compiler Error

Tags: ios, swift, closures

The following code:

```
var index = 0;
for (uuid, type) in map! {
    { (idx) in /*COMPILER ERROR HERE*/
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            Dashlet.build(self.selectedDashboard!.getUuid(), dashletUuid: uuid, type: type) { (dashlet: Dashlet) in
                self.dashlets![idx] = dashlet;

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    var path = NSIndexPath(forRow: idx, inSection:0);
                    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
                });
            };
         });
     } (index);

     index++;
}
```

but this results in a compiler error:

`Cannot convert the expression's type 'Int' to Void`

My wish is to call the dispatch_async as many times as there are entries in the dictionary, and each time with index being one greater than the last time.

EDIT:

Screenshot of actual simplified situation:

[image]

Comment: Try explicitly setting a type for `idx`.  `{ (idx: Int) in`

Comment: @MikeS Thanks for the suggestion, but the same error remains even after doing that.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using? I actually get a compiler crash in Xcode 6.1 GM when I try to compile similar code without the `:Int` in place. If I put the `:Int` there it works fine though.

Comment: @MikeS I am running version Version 6.0.1 (6A317). You think this is a compiler bug?

Comment: Ok, that probably explains the differences we're seeing. You might also be running in to an implicit return type (this doesn't seem to be the case in Xcode 6.1, but it might be in Xcode 6.0.1). If so, you'd fix it by adding an explicit `return` at the end of your closure.  `{ (idx: Int) in /* ... */ return } (index)`.

Comment: @MikeS When I add in the return statement I keep getting a pop up that says `SourceKitService Crashed ...... Editor Functionality Temporarily Limited`. Is that what you meant by compiler crash? Would you recommend bumping up my XCode version?

Comment: I only see a crash when I actually try to compile the code, but you're basically seeing the same thing (SourceKitService does a partial compile to find errors and do syntax highlighting and code completion).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62623/discussion-between-thatidiotguy-and-mike-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be triggering a compiler bug and/or crash in Xcode 6.0.1 and Xcode 6.1 GM (although it manifests itself slightly differently in each).  The way to get around it is to explicitly define the complete closure type.

Instead of:

```
{ (idx) in
```

it would be:

```
{ (idx: Int) -> Void in
```

---

**Update:**

The radar I filed for this [rdar://18571392](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5833802605658112) back in October was just closed; the compiler crash is fixed in Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3 beta 1 (6D520o).

Comment: I actually managed to remove the error by naming the functions instead of passing in anonymous functions, in case that helps anyone else.